# Does express compressed middleware compress request or response?

Tags: express

Per express compression document:

> When using this module with express or connect, simply app.use the module as high as you like. Requests that pass through the middleware will be compressed.

```
var compression = require('compression')
var express = require('express')

var app = express()

// compress all responses
app.use(compression())
```

Understanding express middleware flow, I am confuse on what is actually getting compress. The document says all Request will be compress but the comment stated 'compress all responses'.

It would make sense to compress response that is being sent to client. If it is compressing response, how can it be put "as high as you like" as stated in the document?

Answer (score 1):

That middleware works by taking over all the ways you would write to the `response` stream such as `res.end()`, `res.write()`, etc.. and then compressing the data you send through those methods before it goes out over the network.  The beauty of open source, is you can just go look at [the source](https://github.com/expressjs/compression/blob/master/index.js#L78) yourself and see exactly what it's doing.

So, it is compressing the response your server sends to the client.  "Put as high as you like" means that for a given response, it will only compress responses sent out AFTER this middleware runs for that request.

So, if you had a request handler or middleware that sent a response back to the client and that request handler or middleware ran (on that specific request) before this `compression` middleware ran, then the `compression` middleware would not be hooked in yet and would not be able to do its compression on that request.  So, you would place this middleware before any other middleware or request handlers that you want to have the response they send compressed.

Another way of thinking about this is that this middleware does not install itself globally.  It hooks into each incoming request.  Therefore you have to make sure it gets hooked in before you send out the response.  Otherwise, your response will be sent before the compression gets hooked in (and your response won't get compressed).

Answer (score 1):

"The middleware will attempt to compress response bodies for all request that traverse through the middleware, based on the given options.

This middleware will never compress responses that include a Cache-Control header with the no-transform directive, as compressing will transform the body."

source: https://github.com/expressjs/compression

Answer (score 1):

[Compression](https://npmjs.org/package/compression) middleware compresses response bodies for all given requests that traverse through the middleware. The middleware will not compress responses that include `Cache-Control` header with the `no-transform` directives. This is because doing so will transform the body.

> Understanding express middleware flow, I am confuse on what is actually getting compress. The document says all Request will be compress but the comment stated 'compress all responses'.

This is a misconception. What compression middleware actually does is to compress ***response body*** for all given request passing through the middleware. It does not compress the requests rather it compresses the response body a server sends to a client.

Based on the middleware flow, compression middleware should be placed at the very beginning of an expressjs app configuration, so that it precede other middlewares and routes. This is to make sure your request first passes through the middleware and compresses your response body before your response is being sent.

Comment: But how can they compress the response by placing at the very top when the response is not even constructed yet?

Comment: @Zanko by overwriting the methods in Response object responsible for writing data into it? They replace them with their own methods that compress the input stream before actually sending it over the network? It should explain why putting it at the very top will cover all the responses.